# Why won't my node app and express server run following Google NLP tutorial?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to implement this code in my Node/Express server.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/language?activeTab=readme

```
async function quickstart() {
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const language = require('@google-cloud/language');

  // Instantiates a client
  const client = new language.LanguageServiceClient();

  // The text to analyze
  const text = 'Hello, world!';

  const document = {
    content: text,
    type: 'PLAIN_TEXT',
  };

  // Detects the sentiment of the text
  const [result] = await client.analyzeSentiment({document: document});
  const sentiment = result.documentSentiment;

  console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
  console.log(`Sentiment score: ${sentiment.score}`);
  console.log(`Sentiment magnitude: ${sentiment.magnitude}`);
}
```

The above code I guess cannot be on the frontend react side. So I tried to use it in my app.js file reference it from a GET request, but the server won't compile because it says `require` doesn't exits.

```
app.get('/sentiment', async (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  console.log('sentiment was called'.green.inverse);
  var results = quickstart(req.params);
  res.send(results);
});
```

Not sure how to resolve require or if even implementing this quickstart correctly?

Comment: Show the error. Please.

Comment: You'll run into a couple problems once this code runs. You have to await your async function, and your function should return something.